# Workflow is creating folder in-spite of document set

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, designer-workflow, document-set

I have created a small workflow using SharePoint designer 2013 thats get triggered when a new item is created in "Projects" list.

I want to create a document set in "TestDocLibrary" using workflow after item is added in Projects list.

Please have a look in screen shot of workflow:
 [image]

But this workflow is creating a folder instead of document set. So, how can I create new document set in document library using workflow?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: i want to create document set but it is creating folder.this is the question sir.

Comment: you need to add document set content type on your document library before creating document sets using workflow.

Comment: already added, and also unchecked "Make "New Folder" command available?"  and set it to NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to add document set content type on your document library before creating document sets using workflow.

Also, I found similar [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/45fec8af-b54b-4ac1-9278-1ef0ea1b97a8/creating-document-set-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-via-workflow-creates-a-folder?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious) on social msdn, maye this will help you.

And for more information check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chandru/2013/08/10/sp2013-creating-document-set-using-workflow/) blog.

Comment: Thanks for This Link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chandru/2013/08/10/sp2013-creating-document-set-using-workflow/.